Deleting a folder that doesn't seem empty
Using Java, I'm trying to delete files and folders on a NAS. Everything works perfectly, except when a user has opened Windows Explorer in a folder I want to delete.
For example, I have a folder A which contains a folder B. I want to delete folder B and then folder A. Folder B will be deleted, but not folder A. This only happens when someone uses Windows Explorer in folder B. My code says that folder A is not empty, it still contains folder B. But how can this be because folder B has just been deleted, and in Windows Explorer I can't see folder B (even though hidden files are checked).
I've tried running this code locally and it works even though I have Windows Explorer open in folder B. This only happens with the NAS. Do you have any ideas?
boolean isSuccessfullyRemoved 
void test(){
    isSuccessfullyRemoved = true
    Path p = Paths.get('FOLDER B')
    try (def ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(p)) {
        ds.each { subPath ->
            // Delete every files in the folder B
            if (subPath.toFile().isFile()) {
                deleteFileorFolder(subPath)
            }
        }
    }

    // The folder B should be empty if the deletion of the files was successful and does not contains a folder
    if (isSuccessfullyRemoved && isDirEmpty(p)) {
        // Delete Folder B
        deleteFileorFolder(p)

        // Folder B has been deleted, isSuccessfullyRemoved is TRUE but isDirEmpty is FALSE, why?
        if (isSuccessfullyRemoved && isDirEmpty(p.parent)) {
            deleteFileorFolder(p.parent)
        }
    }
}

boolean isDirEmpty(Path directory) {
    try (def ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(directory)) {
        return !ds.iterator().hasNext()
    }
}

void deleteFileorFolder(Path p) {
    try {
        Files.delete(p)
    } catch (ignored) {
        isSuccessfullyRemoved = false
    }
}


It is hard to follow as you've missed out chunks of code, for example deleteDirectory and deleteFileorFolder, and nothing sets isSuccessfullyRemoved = false.

Not an answer but just an observation on an easier way to reproduce this issue:
// Setup a path to temp directory on NAS:
Path sub = Path.of("F:/Temp/Parent/Child/Sub");
Files.createDirectories(sub);

// Open explorer to Child
Desktop.getDesktop().open(sub.getParent().toFile());
Thread.sleep(10000L);

// Now try to delete
Files.delete(sub);
Files.delete(sub.getParent());
Files.delete(sub.getParent().getParent());

// If the explorer is open then the last delete fails with:
// => Exception java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: F:\Temp\Parent
//       at WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete (WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:270)
//       at AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete (AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:104)
//        at Files.delete (Files.java:1152)

It problem is easier to spot if don't ignore exceptions:
static void deleteFileorFolder(Path p) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("deleteFileorFolder "+p);
    Files.delete(p);
}


If anyone wants to debug, the misleading error code is created around here: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/windows/classes/sun/nio/fs/WindowsFileSystemProvider.java#L266
